# Calculate date based on number of weeks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a spreadsheet that has a start date, duration, and end date. I'm working on a project where dates shift and I'd like Excel to calculate the end date automatically.

In the example below, C13 has a start date of 11/10/15. D13 has a duration of 2 weeks. I want E13 to show the end date.

I saw these formulas on SuperUser, but I couldn't tweak either one to make it work:

```
=TODAY() + 7*12

=TODAY() + 7*(no of weeks)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to your examples, but you refer to the cell with the start date instead of using today's date.  So E13 would be:

```
=C13+7*D13
```

Format the result as a date.  Excel stores dates in units of days, so 7 x number of weeks adds that many days to the starting date.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I'm sorry, I don't mean to shout, but I've been trying to figure this out forever. My work group will be so grateful!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can write if your start date is in C2  and number of weeks in D2 in end date =C2 +D2*7 you will have the end date